# 関数をjQueryのcssのメソッドで使いたいです

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
const color1 = "red"               
$(`.shape${i}`).css(`"background-color", "${color1}"`)
```

と書きましたが　実際ブラウザでみると効いていません。色々ググりましたが見つけられませんでした。
よかったらお力借りたいです。おねがいします。

Answer (score 0):

バッククォート ` で囲った部分は1つの文字列になりますので、提示されているコードでは`css()`関数を「`"background-color", "red"`」という1つの引数で呼んでいます。

`background-color` と `red`は別の文字列にして2つの引数を指定するのが意図でしょうから、

```
$(`.shape${i}`).css("background-color", `${color1}`);
```

または

```
$(`.shape${i}`).css("background-color", color1);
```

となります。